# Qt4.1 setWhtatsthis with QComboBox

Tags: qt4

In Qt4.1 `setWhatsThis` function is not working with `QComboBox`, although it is working with `QLineEdit` and other `QWidget`.

Comment: Code:
QComboBox *ddEOFMode;
ddEOFMode = new QComboBox(groupBox2_2);
ddEOFMode->addItem(QApplication::translate("fConfig", "added item1", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
ddEOFMode->addItem(QApplication::translate("fConfig", "added item 2", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
ddEOFMode->addItem(QApplication::translate("fConfig", "added item3", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
ddEOFMode->setWhatsThis(QApplication::translate("fConfig", "whatsthis for ddeof", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));

Comment: Can't understand a thing !